# Field testing iPhone for Cell ID and RSSI

Tags: iphone

I need to write a testing application to retrieve info about `cell id` and `rssi` on iphone4 IOS 4.2.1, like FieldTest application (Calling *3001#12345#* view UMTS Cell Enviroment/GSM Cell Enviroment).

I have tried to import CoreTelephony framework and using private API (`CTServerConnectionCreate`/`CTServerConnectionCellMonitorStart`).

In this way I am able to retrieve info if I connect to 2g network.

If enable 3G, when I call `CTServerConnectionCellMonitorGetCellCount`, cellcount is always 0.

How can I retrieve these info if connected to 3G Network?

Comment: hi,can you post your code or your xcode file?
I need to get the cell id and rssi on iphone4 IOS 4.2.1,but I had serched so many code,but all could not work.poor.

Comment: I use this function in 2G too, the rssi value is about 100 to 90;
in 3G the rssi value is about 40 - 60 ;
some body say this function is just enable in 3g.

Answer (score 2):

I am working in a such application, i try to retrive cellId, lac and rssi values.
I found a solution for rssi value:

```
void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
if( CTGetSignalStrength == NULL) NSLog(@"Could not find CTGetSignalStrength");  
int result = CTGetSignalStrength();
dlclose(libHandle);
```

for the 2 other values i didn't found any way to retrive them even on a 2G network, can you post your code, i will test it and try to get it working on a 3G network.

Comment: Using this function doesn't seem to produce reliable results.  At the very least, it seems extremely noisy.  If I have my status bar setup to display numerical RSSI, I can run this code over and over again and get significantly different values with the same RSSI dBm value displayed on the status bar.  Not sure why ...

Comment: Any update on RSSI quality? Is it possible to retrieve also RSCP (signal level), SC (Scrambling Code) and EcNo (Signal To Noise Ratio)?